# show data from 2 collections on single page with mongoose node.js

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose

I currently have a profile page in which I show products from the "products" collection in my database. I also want to show a table on the page with results from the "payments" collection in my database but I'm unsure how to merge the queries?

The Products Query:

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res){
Products.find({'username': req.user.username}).sort('-date').exec(function(err, docs){

    res.render('profile', { title: 'Your Products',
    products: docs,
    firstname:req.user.firstName,
    lastname:req.user.lastName,
    email:req.user.email,
    username:req.user.username,
  });

});
```

});

The Payments Query:

```
 app.get('/profile', function(req, res){
    Payments.find({'paidby': req.user.username}).sort('-date').exec(function(err, docs){
        res.render('profile', {payment: docs});

    });
    });
```

How can I load two of these queries into my profile page at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Promises for this type of problem.
First of all you have to configure mongoose to use native promises:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Do this at startup.
After you've done this you can do the following:

```
var paymentPromise = Payments.find({ 'paidby': req.user.username }).sort('-date').exec();
var productPromise = Products.find({ 'username': req.user.username }).sort('-date').exec();

Promise.all([paymentPromise, productPromise]).then(
    docs => {
        let paymentDocs = docs[0];
        let productDocs = docs[1];

        res.render('profile', {
            title: 'Your Products',
            products: productDoc,
            payment: paymentDocs,
            firstname: req.user.firstName,
            lastname: req.user.lastName,
            email: req.user.email,
            username: req.user.username,
        });
    }
);
```